# In the LaTeX package XSIM, how do I get points in parentheses right after the question?

Tags: brackets, xsim, points

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[verbose]{xsim}
\begin{document}
\begin{exercise}[points = 4]
    Solve the equation \[ 3(x-2) + 7 = x + 3 \]
\end{exercise}
\end{document}
```

The output:

[image]

I would like (ignore the font differences):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

"Solved" by adding this to the preamble:

```
\DeclareExerciseEnvironmentTemplate{custom}{%
\GetExerciseHeadingF{\subsection*}%
    {\XSIMmixedcase{\GetExerciseName}\nobreakspace
    \GetExerciseProperty{counter}
\IfInsideSolutionF{%
    \GetExercisePropertyT{points}{\normalfont %
        (%
         \printgoal{\PropertyValue}
         \IfExerciseGoalSingularTF{points}
            {\XSIMtranslate{point}}
            {\XSIMtranslate{points}}%
        )%
    }}%
}%
\par}

\DeclareExerciseType{problem}{
    exercise-env = problem ,
    solution-env = answer ,
    exercise-name = Problem ,
    solution-name = Answer ,
    exercise-template = custom ,
    solution-template = custom
}
```

Output now yields:

[image]